# What does "Return Not (s Is Nothing)" return

Tags: vb.net

Can someone explain me the behaviour of the following line in VB

```
Return Not (s Is Nothing)
```

I am looking to translate this in C# and i am not sure about those negation and do not understand the conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return s != null;
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I understand those negation better now.

Answer (score 5):

In C# this would be

```
return s != null
```

A more direct transaltion is

```
return !(s == null)
```

but that would be odd looking in C# so the original translation is prefered.

Comment: I also find the fact that it returns a boolean confusing. I would have expected it to mean "return s if it isn't null" instead of "return is s null or not"

Comment: DrDro, I can see how you might see it that way, but what would it return if s is null? It has to return something. If it would just return null if s was null then that just be `return s`

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI, in “idiomatic” VB, this would rather be written as:

```
Return s IsNot Nothing
```

Comment: Sounds more natural, anyway :)